# How long should I leave the light on?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits

I remember my old physics teacher at school saying that if you switch a light on in a room and you're planning to return relatively quickly, it uses less electricity if you leave the light on until you return as switching the light on uses more eletricity than leaving it on for a relatively short period, but how long before leaving it on becomes more energy consuming than switching it off until you return and switching it on again?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/85115

Answer (score 1):

A typical light bulb used to light up a bedroom (the original Edison invented incandescent light bulb and not the weak LED ones) uses about 100 W. That means that it is using 100 Joules of electrical energy in 1 sec. 
Switching basically takes no power.
 So, even if you leave for a second, you would still be saving power when you turn it off.

Comment: $100\text{ W}$ in your bedroom?

Comment: That is bright isn't it? lol. I think i did used to have a 100W in my bedroom though, to tell the truth: bare too, no lampshade. It was horrible.

Comment: It is on the bright side.

Answer (score 0):

> The extra energy used to start a *fluorescent lamp* is equivalent to a few seconds of normal operation; it is more *energy*-efficient to switch off lamps when not required for several minutes. [Emphasis mine.]

<sup>[*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp#Frequent_switching)</sup>

Note that this answers (the body of) your question i) for fluorescent lamps and ii) doesn't take into account the effects on the lifespan (and adequate luminosity) of the lamps.

Comment: I the point you're making in ii) that it doesn't matter what the lamp's lifespan is?

Comment: @bluesh34 Well, your question is only concerned with energy consumption, which I take to mean your energy bill. Frequent cycling on and off (of fluorescent lamps) will diminish the life span of the lamps and will increase your lamp bill.

Comment: +1 thanks for the info. I've also posted the question on the electrical engineering site and the answer given says that it's best to switch off except in the case of energy saving bulbs, which it's bes to leave on unless you're planning  to be away for more than 15 minutes.

Comment: @bluesh34 FYI: It is frowned upon by some to cross-post questions on the SE sites. I don't care though. :)

Comment: +1 for info. lol. I'm glad I didn't get in your bad books.